# Javascript Countdown Variable

Tags: javascript, countdown

I am trying to get the date to change to second date. On the first date, I would like it to show Starts: in bold and then the remaining time.  I have it figured to change to a second date.  When it changes to the second date, i want it to show Ends: in bold then the remaining time.  When both countdown timers end, I want it to display text saying the event has ended.  Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("July 23, 2020 21:07:00").getTime();
var countDownDate2 = new Date("July 23, 2020 21:08:00").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var distance2 = countDownDate2 - now;
  var a;
if (distance < 0 && distance2 >0) {
    a = distance2; 
} else {
    a = distance;
}

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(a / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Starts: " + days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // Change to another exp.
  if (distance < 0 && distance2 >0) {
   function changeDate() {
   a = distance2; 
   }
  }
  
// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance2 < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}}, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: not clear, you want a countdown until the first date, then when this one has passed (show=`starts`) a countdown until the second date (show=`Ends`), then a stopwatch on the time elapsed since the second date ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you basically have it figured out, if I'm understanding the question. You just need another variable for the Start/End label, and then use it when you set `.innerHTML` of the demo element.

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
   
//var countDownDate = new Date("July 23, 2020 21:07:00").getTime();
var countDownDate = Date.now() + 5000; // using a shorter time for testing purposes;
// var countDownDate2 = new Date("July 23, 2020 21:08:00").getTime();
var countDownDate2 = Date.now() + 10000;

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var distance2 = countDownDate2 - now;
  var a;
  var label = 'Starts: ';
if (distance < 0 && distance2 >0) {
    a = distance2;
    label = 'Ends: ';
} else {
    a = distance;
}

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(a / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((a % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<strong>" + label + "</strong>" + days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // Change to another exp.
  if (distance < 0 && distance2 >0) {
   function changeDate() {
   a = distance2; 
   }
  }
  
// If the count down is over, write some text 
if (distance2 < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
}}, 1000);
</script>
```